# Is $\rm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_q,\mathbb C_p)=0$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Assume $p\neq q$ are two primes. By $\mathbb Z_q$ I mean the p-adic integers, and by Hom I mean group homomorphisms.

If $\rm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_q, \mathbb C_p) \neq 0$: is the set of **continuous** homomorphisms 0?

If that's too difficult: How about $\rm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_q, \mathbb A_p)$ with $\mathbb A_p$ the ring of integers in $\mathbb C_p$?

Comment: What have you tried? If you just give it some thought, I think you should see that if you allow discontinuous homomorphisms, there will be uncountably many of them; while if you demand continuity, there won’t be any at all.

Comment: Continuity is key here. Note that $\mathbb Z$ is dense in $\mathbb Z_q$, so any such homomorphism would have to be completely determined by where it sends $1$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the hint with the density was helpful. I was irritated because I read in some lecture notes that the usual group homomorphisms were 0 and I thought I was missing some crucial point.